# Apache Nifi PutMongoRecord inserts with different Schemas

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a Nifi instance and would like to write records in Mongodb from there. But these have different schemas. As an example:

```
{"user": "test", "host": "computer1", "process_name": "cmd.exe"}
{"user": "test", "host": "computer1", "domain": "test.test.com"}
```

when I read this with PutMongoRecord and write it to the DB. Then this is treated as if it were one schema and both records have the key "domain" and "process_name". Just with a null value. Is there a possibility that the schema is not interpreted and the records are inserted as they are into the DB?